# Will an RF modulator provide NTSC System M spec video from a DVD player?

Tags: rf, modulation, video, tv, ntsc

I've been attempting to recreate the effect of an old NTSC television broadcast lately with the use of DVDs. The DVD-Video spec allows for up to 720 x 480 pixels at a display rate of 29.97 frames per second, interlaced.

My DVD player is outputting composite video to an RF modulator which is then connected to my TV and the signal is demodulated by the receiver, effectively simulating the NTSC transmission model.

What I'm wondering is if RF modulators output NTSC System M spec video for everything you feed it, allowing for a maximum video bandwidth of 4.2 MHz or about 330 lines of horizontal resolution (440 x 486 from a digital perspective), or if it's converting the composite video signal to RF however it sees fit and the resulting image will look more like 540 line DVD?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on the specific modulator, but RF signal output is just basically the same composite video it gets but modulated to RF.

So the RF output will be NTSC-M if the baseband CVBS that is sent to modulator is also NTSC-M compliant, and that the modulator modulates it in NTSC-M compliant way.

Some sources can/may output non-broadcast compliant CVBS baseband signals, because the output is meant to be connected to a TV or other equipment, and not meant to be transmitted over RF in a compliant fashion. The modulator can and will most likely limit the bandwidth to fit the signal to the RF channel, but it will still modulate whatever compliant or non-compliant signal it gets in.

Comment: Nope nope nope. Not for any real DVD player sold on the market.

Comment: I suggest to read the book Video Demystifed by Keith Jack, and you might have a different view.

Comment: I literally designed TV encoder IP for a living. And DVD players. And media chips with TV encoders (and decoders.) This is my wheelhouse. And I can tell you that no DVD player chip *since the very beginning of DVD* supports this mythical extended-bandwidth composite. That's what Y/C is for.

Comment: In few applications I have used Analog Devices encoders that did allow for up to 6 MHz bandwidth, on NTSC too, not just PAL. That is my understanding from those times. Granted, it was long time ago, and I've been doing digital video like SDI and HDMI since. Certainly, DVD chipsets may only output compliant signals.

Comment: I had the Pioneer Laser Disk in 1981 and it had 425 H lines of resolution on NTSC.  smokie and the Bandit and ABBA were burnt into my memory cells as I used the signal to test my Moog synth for TV scrambler descrambler demonstrations

Comment: Laserdisc used the NTSC composite signal as the master and is inherently an analog format. It's identical to NTSC bandwidth, 4.2MHz. LD is *very* good at faithfully recording and reproducing NTSC, especially when compared to consumer tape. A lot of innovation surrounded decoding it better (Faroudja, etc.) But it was still 4.2MHz NTSC (or PAL) at its core, nothing more.

Comment: How come most online sources have NTSC LaserDisc at 425 lines and PAL at 440? Wouldn't that put it around 5.3 - 5.6 MHz?

Comment: PAL has more lines and can use more bandwidth, 5-6 MHz depending on which standard is used.

Comment: I understand that, I was just referring to @hacktastical's point about LD being 4.2 MHz NTSC when everywhere online says NTSC LD is 425 lines. Not doubting it, just curious as to why that is.

Comment: Thought I'd come back to this in case anyone else had the same question. You were right. On a multiburst pattern, tested on multiple DVD players on multiple displays, they all had extended luma bandwidth of 6.75MHz over composite. Chroma also seemed to go well beyond 1.3MHz. It's only when I sent composite through a VCR's modulator that luma was bandlimited to 5-6MHz (PAL), which makes sense as audio now had to be carried over the same cable, 6MHz above luma.

Answer (score 1):

The DVD player composite encoder will low-pass filter the 720x480 YCbCr digital picture prior to encoding in NTSC or PAL. This is to comply with the spec for baseband composite, allowing the video signal to fit in the allotted RF bandwidth prior to modulation.

If the composite video exceeds that allotted 4.2MHz bandwidth, bad things happen to the sound carrier when they get modulated to RF, so that's why it's not supported or available on a DVD player.

Y/C (S-video) is the step-up alternative that provides better luma bandwidth (although chroma is still limited to that provided by composite).

So the number of lines on baseband composite is only as good as RF composite format allows - about 330 lines, as you state.

---

So why did (and do) DVD players limit composite video bandwidth, even though it's technically possible to send higher resolution signal if RF isn't in the signal chain?

It's not a technical issue, but a marketing one.

In 1997, when DVD was introduced, TV coax-in was the norm. Sets with A/V inputs were still a premium item. High end cinephiles adopted DVD component for home theater, migrating from (composite) laserdisc. They upgraded their whole signal chains because, well, they could.

Meanwhile, low-end consumers delayed their TV upgrade for HDTV (1999) and/or flatscreen+HDMI (2002-ish). In those several in-between years they soldiered along with coax-in RF or, if they were lucky, A/V-in until their TV upgrade cycle came, and with it, new-TV choices sporting a slew of better inputs including Y/C (S-video), component, and slightly later, HDMI.

We can divide the DVD player era into two distinct time periods:

- Pre-HDMI (1997-2002): Component for high-end, RF for cheapskates and Grandma
- Post-HDMI (2002 onward): Whoo-hoo! A new big ol' flatscreen from Costco! Forget RF!

In either pre- or post-HDMI era, there was *no* incentive for 'better', non-RF-compatible composite in a DVD player. Pre-HDMI it would have been an annoyance for the many, many RF users. Post-HDMI, buyers couldn't care less about juiced-up composite because there were so many better connection choices on the new flatscreen TVs whether they wanted HDMI or not.

And let's not forget about the content providers who were freaking out at the idea of *any* higher-quality format enhancing the ability to capture analog out to re-encode for 'piracy' (nevermind DeCSS rendering that point moot). The *last* thing they wanted was *better* composite (let alone component); they worked really hard to make it *worse* with Macrovision. That rights-freakout hellbeast carried over to HDMI, with its own fun set of problems and hassles.

Anyway. And now, storytime. My first trip to Costco, January 2005. Standing in the next checkout line, a younger, Santa Cruz Mountains looking dude with exactly two items on a flat cart:

- 40" Vizio TV
- handle of Tanqueray

And I thought to myself, "*that* cowboy is ready to *par-tay!*"

Comment: The DVD players might limit the bandwidth. However the output of these devices is not meant to be directly broadcasted with a compliant transmitter, so luminance information from composite sources can be present at up to 6-7 MHz to have better quality.

Comment: That doesn't follow industry practice for any video gear on the market. Why? CPST is limited to 4.5MHz to prevent intrusion into sound carrier when modulated on RF. It will actually flunk validation on a test set (e.g., VM700) if it doesn't. On the other hand, Y/C provides that extended luma bandwidth when the gear supports it.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure whether composite video from DVD players/video game consoles was fully NTSC/PAL-compliant or just followed their colour encoding. How come S-Video/RGB can look sharper on old video game consoles with resolutions as low as 256x224 like the Super Nintendo though? Is this purely to do with the separation of luma and chroma? Will composite video always max out at ~330 TVL for NTSC video?

Comment: If it is broadcast equipment, then it has to follow broadcast standards. If it is home DVD equipment or professional studio equipment, the composite is not meant to be broadcast over RF anyway, not without further processing, only between equipment, so it does not have to pass tests that are meant for composite signals that will be broadcasted over RF. Even if it is modulated to RF for a TV set, the modulator would limit the composite bandwidth before adding sound carrier. Even then it can have higher chroma bandwidth than meant for RF broadcast.

Comment: @Justme - no real DVD player does that. They always bandlimit CPST to avoid compatibility issues and angry system integrators / customers / bad reviews.

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by "CPST"? A quick Google/wiki search didn't help.

Comment: CPST is shorthand for 'composite'. Sometimes called CVBS, for Chroma, Video, Blanking and Sync. This is one of the two things that make up an over-the-air TV signal, the other being sound, which is sent on an FM carrier just above the video.

Comment: Keith Jack says in his book that while the bandwidth of broadcast signal is rigidly defined, there is no such standard for consumer equipment using baseband video. So they can generate higher bandwidth signals to provide sharper picture.

Comment: Keith Jack notwithstanding, that's not what the DVD industry did, for the reasons I stated: to avoid compatibility issues with RF modulators.

Comment: Do you know if PAL DVDs similarly conformed to PAL composite video?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Electrical Engineering.

Your video quality is likely to be limited by the fact that you are using composite video rather than anything the modulator is doing. The colour difference signal needs to be restricted in bandwidth before being added to the composite signal. The TV has various options for separating the luminance (black + white) and colour difference signals out of the composite signal. The cheaper options will restrict the luminance bandwidth.

I played around with the various connection options when I first got a DVD player (to use with a wide-screen CRT TV). I had a baseband composite video connection, without needing to use a modulator. It was still noticeably worst than the next best quality connection - S-Video.

My best connection was component video but this was only superior to S-Video for menus generated in the DVD player itself. The DVD format records a colour difference signal so there's no extra information for a component video connection to carry in addition to that available via S-Video.

(I'm in the UK so my TV offered RGB for component video rather than YPbPr. The DVD player had both.)